# ios5 iPad: best way to transfer files from PC's over wifi to iPad (network file browser / transfer)

Tags: ios, wifi, file-transfer

I apologize if this has been answered.  We've done a lot of searching and come up with many pieces of the puzzle but no direct answer from someone who has done it.

We have an iPad app where we want to allow the user to select a file browser in the app and browse network drives, select a large file (photo or video up to 1gb) and transfer it to the iPad for local storage.

We do not want the user to have to use iTunes or any additional software on their computer at all.  The files on the pc will be in folders such as "My Pictures" if Windows, etc.  We need it to work on both PC and Mac.

We've looked into Bonjour, CocoaHttpServer, ftp, Samba, SimpleNetworkStreams, CocoaAsyncSocket, and other solutions, but feel like we might be reinventing the wheel and there might be a preferred pipeline for this action.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Will

Comment: Write an application?  Seriously, it's not clear what you are asking.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: We have an application functioning already using the built in ios file sharing through itunes by changing info.plist value "Application supports iTunes file sharing" to yes.  Now, we are attempting to grab files off the network drive via wifi.  The question i am asking is what is the best method or preferred library of code, or function, to do this correctly.  This is mostly a best methods question, not a code snippet needed question.  Looking to be pointed in the right direction and can take it from there.  There might be some function or library that does exactly what we are looking for.

Comment: I am having this same issue.  I don't want to have to use iTunes to get files into my app from my desktop.  I thought there would be something straightforward considering how easy it is to enable file sharing from the Mac settings.